# Merge Candidates: [continuous-integration], [continuous-deployment], [continuous-delivery]

Tags: support, retag-request

[continuous-delivery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continuous-delivery) should definitely be merged into [continuous-integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continuous-integration) and [continuous-deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continuous-deployment) should probably be merged in also.

[image]

Comment: Continuous integration and continuous deployment are actually two different (but related) things.  But continuous-delivery should definitely be burned.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the tags [continuous-delivery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continuous-delivery), [continuous-integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continuous-integration) and [continuous-deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continuous-deployment) are not good tags for this site. They are actually different things, also the precise meaning is often misunderstood, different people does have a different understanding about what these are - also the term "CI/CD" is used in a mix in this context.

These tags are ***practices*** and questions related to those practices is better asked on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

That said, there are many technical questions related to those practices but it would be better to use more well-defined and well-understood tags for them like:

- [build-automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/build-automation)
- [automated-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automated-tests)
- [deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deployment)
- [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git), [jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins) and specific tools.
- [automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automation) - but this is also a probably too broad tag that may be disambigued.

Answer (score 1):

[According to SemaphoreCI](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2017/07/27/what-is-the-difference-between-continuous-integration-continuous-deployment-and-continuous-delivery.html), they're actually not the same thing. They carry the same goal but at different magnitudes. In a nutshell:

- continuous integration: automated build and test at every merge
- continuous delivery: continuous integration + automated release process + manual deploy
- continuous deployment: continuous integration + automated release process + automated deploy

Although many tools do CI and CDs at the same time, CI is very different from CDs since it doesn't impact production environment. However, [continuous-delivery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continuous-delivery) and [continuous-deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continuous-deployment) are too close to be separate tags, and in practice, many people don't see any difference between them. They should be merged.